# Regex to match post-alveolar consonants

Tags: regex, grep

I have a text file called a.txt that has this elements in it:

```
fall#i#1    fall (as a fruit) (v.)  fall    jatuh   fall (as a fruit) (v.)  jatuh*  t͡ʃampaʔ
dog#n#1 dog dog anjing  dog anjing  ŋand͡ʒi
wing#n#1    wing    wing    sayap   wing    sayap   kopaʔ
fly#i#1 fly (v.)    fly (vb)    terbang fly (v.)    terbang tobaŋ
mosquito#n#1    mosquito    mosquito    nyamuk  mosquito    nyamuk  ɲamuʔ
flower#n#2  flower  flower  bunga (yg jadi buah), kuntum    flower  bunga*  buŋo
sky#n#1 sky sky langit  sky langit* ʔlaŋɪt
```

First, I need a regular expression to match the lines that have final post-alveolar consonant like [ŋɡʔ] the out put should look like this:

```
fall#i#1    fall (as a fruit) (v.)  fall    jatuh   fall (as a fruit) (v.)  jatuh*  t͡ʃampaʔ
wing#n#1    wing    wing    sayap   wing    sayap   kopaʔ
fly#i#1 fly (v.)    fly (vb)    terbang fly (v.)    terbang tobaŋ
mosquito#n#1    mosquito    mosquito    nyamuk  mosquito    nyamuk  ɲamuʔ
```

Second, I need a regular expression to match the post-alveolar at the beginning of the words out put should look like this:

```
dog#n#1 dog dog anjing  dog anjing  ŋand͡ʒi
sky#n#1 sky sky langit  sky langit* ʔlaŋɪt
```

Third, I need a regular expression to match the post-alveolar between vowels like this output:

```
flower#n#2  flower  flower  bunga (yg jadi buah), kuntum    flower  bunga*  buŋo
sky#n#1 sky sky langit  sky langit* ʔlaŋɪt
```

I used to use this regex in Ubuntu terminal to match them all:

```
grep -P '\b[ʔŋɡk]|[ʔŋɡk]\b|[aiueo][ʔŋɡk][aiueo]' a.txt
```

but I couldn't find a regex to match them separately I mean once match post-alveolar at the end another regex match only at the beginning and the other regex match between vowels can any one please help me with that thanks

Comment: @Peter Thoeny can you please answer this question as previous one closed

Comment: Please remove the comment above. You cannot call users like this: they only get notifications if they performed anyaction on the question (closed, commented....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexps you can use are

```sh
grep -P '(*UCP)[ŋɡʔ]\b' file           # 1
grep -P '(*UCP)\b[ŋɡʔ]' file           # 2
grep -P '[aiɪueo][ʔŋɡk][aɪiueo]' file  # 3
```

Where

- `(*UCP)[ŋɡʔ]\b` - matches `ŋ`, `ɡ` or `ʔ` followed with a Unicode-aware (due to `(*UCP)` PCRE verb) word boundary
- `(*UCP)\b[ŋɡʔ]` - matches `ŋ`, `ɡ` or `ʔ` preceded with a Unicode-aware (due to `(*UCP)` PCRE verb) word boundary
- `[aiɪueo][ʔŋɡk][aɪiueo]` matches `ŋ`, `ɡ`, `k` or `ʔ` in between `a`, `i`, `ɪ`, `u`, `e` and `o` vowels (**NOTE** `i` and `ɪ` are not the same letters!)

See a [`grep` demo](https://ideone.com/9cv4pw):

```sh
s='fall#i#1    fall (as a fruit) (v.)  fall    jatuh   fall (as a fruit) (v.)  jatuh*  t͡ʃampaʔ
dog#n#1 dog dog anjing  dog anjing  ŋand͡ʒi
wing#n#1    wing    wing    sayap   wing    sayap   kopaʔ
fly#i#1 fly (v.)    fly (vb)    terbang fly (v.)    terbang tobaŋ
mosquito#n#1    mosquito    mosquito    nyamuk  mosquito    nyamuk  ɲamuʔ
flower#n#2  flower  flower  bunga (yg jadi buah), kuntum    flower  bunga*  buŋo
sky#n#1 sky sky langit  sky langit* ʔlaŋɪt'
grep -P '(*UCP)[ŋɡʔ]\b' <<< "$s"
echo "----"
grep -P '(*UCP)\b[ŋɡʔ]' <<< "$s"
echo "----"
grep -P '[aiɪueo][ʔŋɡk][aɪiueo]' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
fall#i#1    fall (as a fruit) (v.)  fall    jatuh   fall (as a fruit) (v.)  jatuh*  t͡ʃampaʔ
wing#n#1    wing    wing    sayap   wing    sayap   kopaʔ
fly#i#1 fly (v.)    fly (vb)    terbang fly (v.)    terbang tobaŋ
mosquito#n#1    mosquito    mosquito    nyamuk  mosquito    nyamuk  ɲamuʔ
----
dog#n#1 dog dog anjing  dog anjing  ŋand͡ʒi
sky#n#1 sky sky langit  sky langit* ʔlaŋɪt
----
flower#n#2  flower  flower  bunga (yg jadi buah), kuntum    flower  bunga*  buŋo
sky#n#1 sky sky langit  sky langit* ʔlaŋɪt
```

Comment: Stribizew Thanks for answer it works pretty good, I have another problem that I just need to find the data on column T but right now it takes from every column is there any way to just look in specific column?

Comment: @Arman Yes, but in these cases, `awk` that only supports POSIX is recommended.

Comment: I have accepted your answer and Up voted your it thanks again for answer but can you please explain a bit about awk formula that do the same thing that grep -P do to match the words with those characters in specific column thanks.

Comment: @Arman If we assume the fields/columns are separated with whitespace, and the column you need to look for a match is Column 7, you could use something like `awk '$7 ~ /[ŋɡʔ]$/' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/g6arSf).

Comment: thanks for this how if we have tab instead of whitespace should we just change the ~ to \t ? because the file that I have it's separator is tab

Comment: @Arman `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $7 ~ /[ŋɡʔ]$/' file`